# Rust in condensate drip pan

Tags: hvac, rust, condensate

I have a 5 year old high Efficiency Carrier HVAC system. Been having some moisture/condensation issues and was snooping around and noticed quite a bit of buildup of rust in my AC condensate drip pan. I also get a little condensation dripping out of the corner of the unit. Appears it’s coming from the drip pan. How normal is this? Should there be that much rust in the pan? Do I need to have this issue resolved/looked at asap? System is working fine. Condensate drip line is not clogged and is clear.  Don’t notice any issues anywhere else.

[Video](https://photos.google.com/share/AF1QipNsXfIEbkawS-6HpDv7D8KJ6pqDNvKhfHBPqPz_9oXIf5xsRoyN4AivA-biQBauLQ/photo/AF1QipODC_0M7T6PmZQTE-7p-NzWZBTKV0wwGIRc5K8x?key=dXl6SmJSdXN2bTFOM0JkS2UxWnptWGVDMnBhaC1R)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That does not look like rust to me. It looks like dirt (from dust collection). Make sure you filters are clean, (the air return filters).

It is normal that the AC sweat a lot in humid air--they are built for that.

If it is just dust/dirt collection it would just smear under your finger.

If it is rust it will not.

Comment: Hi here is the link to the video https://photos.google.com/share/AF1QipNsXfIEbkawS-6HpDv7D8KJ6pqDNvKhfHBPqPz_9oXIf5xsRoyN4AivA-biQBauLQ/photo/AF1QipODC_0M7T6PmZQTE-7p-NzWZBTKV0wwGIRc5K8x?key=dXl6SmJSdXN2bTFOM0JkS2UxWnptWGVDMnBhaC1R

Comment: Watching the video there is rust in there and something is rusting bad it’s still hard to see,  if you can identify the component that is rusting this may help. Buildup of rust will affect the galvanized pan